# Send email containing pdf based on items in table

Tags: c#, email, reporting-services, smtp

I have a program that I lost the source code to and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong now that we had an IP change.  What I am trying to do is step through a table and have it send emails with the corresponding report.  Any ideas what is going wrong?  I don't get any errors but I also don't get any emails (and yes the SMTP server works).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace AutomatedReporting
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

                foreach (var item in dc.reportsSent1s)
                {
                    string matchedCaseNumber = item.CaseNumberKey;
                    (new MyReportRenderer()).RenderTest(matchedCaseNumber);


                }
                dc.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE reportsSent1");
            }



            public class MyReportRenderer
               {
                     private rs2005.ReportingService2005 rs;
                     private rs2005Execution.ReportExecutionService rsExec;

            public void RenderTest(String matchedCaseNumber)
            {
                string HistoryID = null;
                string deviceInfo = null;
                string encoding = String.Empty;
                string mimeType = String.Empty;
                string extension = String.Empty;
                rs2005Execution.Warning[] warnings = null;
                string[] streamIDs = null;


                rs = new rs2005.ReportingService2005();
                rsExec = new rs2005Execution.ReportExecutionService();
                rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                rsExec.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                rs.Url = "http://***.***.***.***/ReportServer_DEVELOPMENT/ReportService2005.asmx";
                rsExec.Url = "http://***.***.***.***/ReportServer_DEVELOPMENT/ReportExecution2005.asmx";



                try
                {
                    // Load the selected report.
                    rsExec.LoadReport("/LawDept/LawDeptTIC", HistoryID);

                    // Set the parameters for the report needed.

                    rs2005Execution.ParameterValue[] parameters = new rs2005Execution.ParameterValue[1];
                    parameters[0] = new rs2005Execution.ParameterValue();
                    parameters[0].Name = "CaseNumberKey";
                    parameters[0].Value = matchedCaseNumber;

                    rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");

                    // get pdf of report 
                    Byte[] results = rsExec.Render("PDF", deviceInfo,
                    out extension, out encoding,
                    out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

                    //pass paramaters for email
                    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();



                    var matchedBRT = (from c in db.GetTable<vw_ProductClientInfo>()
                                      where c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber
                                      select c.BRTNumber).SingleOrDefault();

                    var matchedAdd = (from c in db.GetTable<vw_ProductClientInfo>()
                                      where c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber
                                      select c.Premises).SingleOrDefault();



                    var matchedDocument = (from c in db.GetTable<Document>()
                                           where c.DocIDKey == SelectedRow.DocIDKey
                                           select c).SingleOrDefault();

                    db.Documents.DeleteOnSubmit(matchedDocument);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                    var matchedEmail = (from c in db.GetTable<vw_ProductClientInfo>()
                                        where c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber
                                        select c.Email).SingleOrDefault();

                    //send email with attachment
                    MailMessage message = new MailMessage("Reports@acmetaxabstracts.com", matchedEmail, "Report for property located at " + matchedAdd, "Attached is the Tax Information Certificate for the above captioned property");
                    MailAddress copy = new MailAddress("acmetaxabstracts@gmail.com");
                    message.CC.Add(copy);
                    SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("***.***.***.***");
                    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(results), String.Format("{0}" + matchedBRT + ".pdf", "BRT")));
                    emailClient.Send(message);

                    //db.reportsSent1s.DeleteOnSubmit(matchedItem);
                    //db.SubmitChanges();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                }
            }
        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, why dont you just decompile your original exe/dll?

Comment: Well I thought about that but its a Click Once app and I cannot figure out how to do so.  Whesays " @filename is not a .NET module"

Comment: Awesome I figured it out.  I didn't realize I had to take the .deploy off the exe to decompile it.  Thanks!